# Updates for a private plugin?

Tags: plugins, updates

If I write a private plugin, is there any way to use the WordPress auto-update mechanism to update it?

I want to encapsulate the functionality, but it's specific to my own 5 or so blogs, so it's not a good candidate for the public plugins resource. But I love the easy-updating mechanism.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I believe this was discussed as a filterable option on the wp-hackers mailing list back in the day. It was never resolved, IIRC. I *think* the relevant discussion was in this thread: http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2009-February/024796.html ...but I could be wrong.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own solution, you can use https://kernl.us for hosted plugin updates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Wordpress v5.8, it is a lot simpler to create yourself a basic version of custom plugin update functionality.

#### Step 1

Create JSON file on your server. It will contain info about latest version number of your plugin(s) and link to ZIP file(s) for Wordpress to automatically download it when update is triggered.

Example location: https://my-domain.com/custom-plugins/plugins-info.json

Example content:

```
{
    "my-plugin/my-plugin.php":{
        "version":"1.1",
        "package":"https://my-domain.com/custom-plugins/my-plugin.zip"
    }
}
```

You can add multiple plugins info to that JSON. Just ensure that plugin key for each is in **directory_name/file_name.php** format.

Of course, only when plugin version in JSON is larger than version you have installed, Wordpress will show you that new version is available.

For full list of plugin(s) data you can set in JSON file, check [$update parameter here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_plugins_hostname/)

#### Step 2

Add "Update URI" to plugin's main file (comment section). It should link to your custom JSON file you created in step 1.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My plugin
 * Version:     1.0
 * Update URI:  https://my-domain.com/custom-plugins/plugins-info.json
 * 
 */
```

#### Step 3

Add this code to custom plugin's main file (or to functions.php)

**IMPORTANT:** Change "my-domain.com" inside add_filter function to actual domain you are using for JSON file.

```
if( ! function_exists( 'my_plugin_check_for_updates' ) ){
    
    function my_plugin_check_for_updates( $update, $plugin_data, $plugin_file ){
        
        static $response = false;
        
        if( empty( $plugin_data['UpdateURI'] ) || ! empty( $update ) )
            return $update;
        
        if( $response === false )
            $response = wp_remote_get( $plugin_data['UpdateURI'] );
        
        if( empty( $response['body'] ) )
            return $update;
        
        $custom_plugins_data = json_decode( $response['body'], true );
        
        if( ! empty( $custom_plugins_data[ $plugin_file ] ) )
            return $custom_plugins_data[ $plugin_file ];
        else
            return $update;
        
    }
    
    add_filter('update_plugins_my-domain.com', 'my_plugin_check_for_updates', 10, 3);
    
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks!

Comment: How would you protect this against anybody downloading plugin?

Answer (score 51):

Looks like the applicable code is in `wp-includes/update.php`, `wp_update_plugins()`:

```
$to_send = (object) compact('plugins', 'active');

$options = array(
    'timeout' => ( ( defined('DOING_CRON') && DOING_CRON ) ? 30 : 3), 
    'body' => array( 'plugins' => serialize( $to_send ) ),
    'user-agent' => 'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . get_bloginfo( 'url' )
);  

$raw_response = wp_remote_post('http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.0/', $options);
```

It specifically checks api.wordpress.org. Technically speaking it would be possible to pass a key inside `$to_send` to delegate the check, but to my knowledge that is not a supported feature.

If you hook into `set_site_transient_update_plugins` you could add your own package details into this variable. It looks like those values will be trusted when you run the plugin updater. See `wp-admin/update.php` and `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php`. Given the code in these two functions, I think it would be possible to inject your own update server, you just need to look at how the package details are formatted and match that.

Answer (score 45):

This plugin does it for you:

> ### [Automatic Updates For Private And Commercial Plugins](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/)
>
> Since time immemorial, only plugins hosted in the official WordPress.org plugin directory have supported automatic updates. Now, I’ve written a PHP library that you can use to add automatic update capabilities to any plugin. Public, private and commercial plugins alike – all can now enjoy the benefits of automatic update notifications and one-click upgrades.

<sub>[GitHub repository](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker)</sub>

Comment: You may also be interested to manage the plugins on your side ... maybe with the package `wp-update-server`, written by the same author ;) https://github.com/YahnisElsts/wp-update-server By using this server, you can secure your plugins, as described here: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2013/03/19/plugin-updates-securing-download-links/

Comment: how can i disable wordpress default update checker on free plugins?

Comment: Even though that website looks outdated, the project is very actively supported, and it works with private Bitbucket/Github repos too! See their Github repo for more info on the different integrations available https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker

Answer (score 10):

If you like free ... and want to use something like GitHub, GitLab, or BitBucket, this is a good quality and supported plugin for handling it (supports private and enterprise):

https://github.com/afragen/github-updater

Comment: Wow! Looks like a well-supported and mature project!

Comment: Relying on another plugin doesn't seem a very clean solution.

Comment: @kontur very true, but being as though this is open source, and constantly being updated, it could be used as a framework, or just as a code example to build your own with.

Answer (score 8):

I'm looking into the same thing. A couple of links that I've found that might be helpful:

- [**WordPress.org Plugin Information API Docs**](http://dd32.id.au/projects/wordpressorg-plugin-information-api-docs/)
- [**get_api_data() on Pastebin**](https://pastebin.com/7Ji8rD2P)

The first is some info and pointers to the upgrades API. The second is a code snippet showing how to actually request info from the API.

#### get_api_data()

```
<?php
/*
Retrieve items from the plugin API
*/
function get_api_data($per_page, $page)
{
    $fields = array(
        'downloaded' => true,
        'author' => false,
        'author_profile' => false,
        'contributors' => false,
        'requires' => true,
        'tested' => false,
        'compatibility' => false,
        'homepage' => false,
        'description' => false,
        'last_updated' => true,
        'added' => true
    );
    $body = (object) array('browse' => 'new', 'page' => $page, 'per_page' => $per_page, 'fields' => $fields);
    $post_data = array('action' => 'query_plugins', 'request' => serialize($body));
 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
 
    return unserialize($return);
}
```

Comment: *@Dougal* - Nice links!

Comment: The second link is dead, this is the reason why you really should try to include content from external links from the beginning if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [WordPress Development Kit plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dev-kit/faq/).   I recently migrated my proprietary update system to this plugin.  The plugin now serves as the back-end processor for my premium plugin updates.

This is similar in setup to the solution provided by agileapricot above.   It will install as a standard plugin on a WordPress site.  You host your premium .zip files and the plugins.json in production or prerelease directories on your server (specified in the settings for the plugin).

The plugin also allows you to list plugin versions and can even provide a download for the files on public, password-protected, or subscription-protected pages.  You can see an example of the [on-page version list here](http://www.storelocatorplus.com/support/documentation/store-locator-plus/release-notes/slp-versions/).

I have been using the plugin for months to publish the change log for my premium add-ons, the current versions list, and download lists for my Premier Subscription holders.   Now, with version 0.7.01, it is working as the query destination for inline WordPress updates.

Hope some of you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a hosted solution that you don't have to manage, check out Kernl (https://kernl.us).  Its a service that provides the infrastructure for updating plugins and makes it easy to integrate into your own plugins.

Comment: This seems viable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in creating your own update server, it is easy enough to do without libraries using only two filter hooks `plugins_api` and `site_transient_update_plugins`

`plugins_api` – used to get the plugin information and display it in modal window, example:

[image]

`site_transient_update_plugins` is needed to push the update from your server.

More on that in this tutorial: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/self-hosted-plugin-update.html

Comment: I have tried your code but getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Comment: In this code i am getting the error // do nothing if we don't get the correct response from the server
 if( 
  is_wp_error( $remote )
  || 200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $remote )
  || empty( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $remote ) 
 ) {
  return $res; 
 }

Comment: )  missing in your code

Answer (score -2):

you can use this commercial plugin: http://autohosted.com/
no limitation and have several other feature you might need:

- No monthly charge
- Unlimited use
- Easy integration with Themes and Plugins
- Authentication by domains, keys, & roles

Comment: It's closed to new signups...