# How To Update Premium Plugins I made

Tags: plugin-development, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updates for a private plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13/updates-for-a-private-plugin)

I am trying to find a way to update my premium plugins for WP. My current needs are that:

- the system I use must allow for multiple plugins (although if it only allows for one plugin I can modify it to make it work for several.
- the system I use should protect the URL of the source file
- the system I use should be easy to update and **must work**

I do not want my code on Github (for obvious reasons as they are premium plugins).

Comment: Do you want to remotely update WordPress plugin, which has already been activated on users WordPress sites, right ?

Comment: @amit Yes, that is the goal

Comment: @Kaiser Objection to this being a duplicate. Yes I agree the question is a duplicate, but the question linked is over 2 years old. Alot of WordPress has changed in two years.

Comment: Have you tried the other answer, and can confirm, that it's not working anymore?

Comment: It works but it is extrodinarily insecure. If you set it up where the server side file (lets just say; doesn't really matter what its called) update.php or something like that, and you directly navigate to this page in your browser it downloads the whole php file, showing the location of the premium plugin's zip folder. On top of that, it does not support multiple plugins (been trying to get it to for like an hour now).