# Are automatic background plugin updates for non-WP.org plugins possible?

Tags: automatic-updates

Is is possible to update plugins automatically in the background that are not hosted in the official WP.org repository?

We have the [`auto_update_$type` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates#Plugin_.26_Theme_Updates_via_Filter) to add these plugin slugs to the update cycle, but I have trouble getting it to work.

Can somebody confirm this is possible and how it is done correctly?

Comment: yes it is possible (I still need to implement it). EDD has a module for that and with some googling you will find code on github (linked from this site if you want to search here). As for "how it is done correctly", you will probably need to explain how you do it now which results in incorrect behaviour, it is impossible to guess what code you use ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updates for a private plugin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13/updates-for-a-private-plugin)

Comment: I was thinking that there should be no reason why this is not possible. It's propably related to the Github Updater plugin I'm using. Thanks.