# Updates for a private theme

Tags: customization, themes, updates, deployment

I wrote a own theme and I dont wanna deploy it by myself.

The customer should do that himself. I found [*this*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13/updates-for-a-private-plugin) solution for plugins. But it doesn't work for themes. Is there an alternative to  `add_filter( 'update_plugins_(hostname)` for themes?

Comment: You can hook pre_set_site_transient_update_themes, e.g. [article on the Make blog](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/30/recommended-usage-of-the-updates-api-to-support-the-auto-updates-ui-for-plugins-and-themes-in-wordpress-5-5/).

Comment: Since WP 6.1, there is a `update_themes_{$hostname}` filter for themes:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_themes_hostname/

Comment: @leemon How does that work? What host name does that use? Please post an answer if you know the details.

Comment: @Rup Not tried it myself, but here there's an example using the `update_plugins_{$hostname}` filter that you can use as a blueprint for themes: https://nickgreen.info/add-autoupdates-to-your-wordpress-plugin-thats-hosted-on-github-using-update_plugins_hostname/