# Private plugin updating - GitHub zip file changes the plugin directory (with release or branch name)

Tags: plugins, github

I am trying to automate the updating of private custom plugins. I found this question:
[Updates for a private plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13/updates-for-a-private-plugin), which works brilliantly. I have the zip files on a website and WordPress detects the upgrade to the plugin and the user can then ask for the update.

The problem I am having is that GitHub adds the version onto the plugin directory, once it is upzipped so:

- `myplugin` -> `myplugin-1.9`

Because of this feature of GitHub, WordPress thinks it is a new plugin and the user has to re-activate it after the update.

UPDATE

I have since watched the code run in WP_Upgrader and there doesn't seem to be a hook or filter in which I can change the final directory for the plugin.

I did add some code to the filter `upgrader_post_install` to rename the directory, which worked, but too hacky for a final solution.

I do not see a moment where I can hop in and ask the directory be changed from `myplugin-1.9` to `myplugin`.  I have reached the conclusion for now, that I will instead build the zip file myself to ensure it does not have the version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to carefully adjust the **destination** path via the [`upgrader_package_options`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_package_options/) filter in WordPress, before the upgrader installs the new version of it.

Here's a barebone example that appends the plugin's current directory name to the **destination** path, if it's same as `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` (see check in core [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L549)), when the **package** url is a `github.com` domain:

```
add_filter( 'upgrader_package_options', function( $options ) {

    $destination = $options['destination'] ?? '';
    $package     = $options['package'] ?? '';
    $dirname     = isset( $options['hook_extra']['plugin'] ) 
                   ? dirname( $options['hook_extra']['plugin'] )
                   : '';
    
    if ( empty( $dirname ) || '.' === $dirname ) {
        return $options;
    }

    if ( 'github.com' !== parse_url( $package, PHP_URL_HOST) ) {
       return $options;
    }
    
    if ( WP_PLUGIN_DIR === $destination ) { 
        $options['destination'] = path_join( $destination, $dirname );
    }

    return $options;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up debugging and watching WP_Upgrader class unpack the plugin and $destination holds only the plugin directory.  I will be updating my question, because I cannot find a hook or filter to use after stepping through the code.

Comment: @Katie Thanks for the info. I've updated the snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  So it seems the $options['destination'] normally has just the /plugins directory in it, but when you add /plugins/plugin-name directory to it, then it forces the directory name of the plugin?

Comment: Yes that is how I understand it  and the WP_PLUGIN_DIR comparison should also target only plugins and not themes.